# How to sum a row in matrix without numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, sum

How do I check the sum of a row without numpy?
If I have this code:

```
Matrix = [["X", "X", "X"],[ "O", "O", "X"], ["X", "O", "X"]]
```

How do I check the sum of every row in the matrix without numpy?

Example:

In the matrix above my sum would be `x = "XXX", "OOX", "XOX"`

**EDIT**

I do not like to use stuff like `.join` and `.map`.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: "I do not like to use stuff like `.join` and `.map`"? Get over it.

Comment: You should use join! Alternatively explain why you cannot use the standard functions in python. Also change _sum_ to _concatenate_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't create a matrix. It errors out. 
If you want to represent a matrix with lists, you could do the following:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,0]]
```

You could then find the sum of each row with a list comprehension:

```
[sum(row) for row in matrix]
```

EDIT: The question has changed, so for later readers I want to make sure it's clear. sum will add numbers, not concatenate strings. If you want to concatenate strings, your list comprehension should look like this:

```
[[''.join(row) for row in matrix]]
```

If you want to assign names to each row, instead of creating a separate variable for each, stick the list of sums into a for loop and assign each sum to a dictionary:

```
sum_dict = {}
i=0
for s in sum_list:
    sum_dict['r'+str(i)] = s
    i +=1
```

Will give you a dictionary with keys r0,r1,r2, etc.

Comment: I am getting this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: That is strange. What exactly does your code look like? Those two lines alone work for me.

In your question you have strings, but your error implies ints. What does your matrix look like?

Comment: Try restarting your kernel . Did you assign an int to the variable name sum?

If at any point you have something like sum=5, then you will have overwritten the sum function. If you restart python it should work.

Comment: If my output is `[3, 5, 1]` it but is there a way to convert it, so it will be `o = 3, o1 = 5, o2 = 0`?

Comment: your solution does not answer the question

Comment: My understanding is that there are reasons to avoid assigning variables on the fly. But if you think about it, in almost every case, you can actually store those variables in a dictionary or other data structure, and doing so makes life easier down the road. In this case, consider using a dictionary. You can loop through the list of sums and assign a key in a dictionary for each.

Comment: @Ohjeah The question has changed several times since I answered it.

Comment: what your answer does is [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,0]] = [3,6,0] where as expected output should be [3,3,3]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *list comprehension* and `str.join`:

```
Matrix = [["X", "X", "X"],[ "O", "O", "X"], ["X", "O", "X"]]
m = [''.join(i) for i in matrix]
print(m)
# ['XXX', 'OOX', 'XOX']
```

To create a more general solution for *adding* different types you can use `reduce` with `operator.add`:

```
from operator import add
# from functools import reduce # Py3

Matrix = [1, 1, 2], ["O", "O", "X"], ["X", "O", "X"]

m = [reduce(add, i) for i in Matrix]
print(m)
# [4, 'OOX', 'XOX']
```

Comment: `from functools import reduce` for python 3

Comment: @Ohjeah Yep, I was going to add that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use join on an empty string:

```
x = [''.join(row) for row in Matrix]
```